# Creating a virtual directory to a non-local (remote) folder in IIS 6

Tags: iis

I have a shared folder on a server that contains some files I want to be able to serve through IIS on a separate server.

I created a virtual directory pointing to the the shared folder in IIS, and have it use windows authentication.

The shared folder has "Everyone" set to have read permissions. When I try to open a file through localhost on the iis server, everything loads correctly, however when I substitute localhost with the actual name of my iis server it brings up an error

```
You do not have permission to view this directory or page due to the access 
control list (ACL) that is configured for this resource on the Web server.
```

I opened up process monitor and saw I was getting Access Denied when the Network Service account (the account my app pool is set to run as) was being denied read permissions to the virtual directory. I implicitly added network service to the security permissions with read and write permissions and I still get the same error.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?